# Base 8 and Base 9 Representations

Tags: number-theory

A positive integer N greater than 1 is described as special if in its base-8 and base-9
representations, both the leading and ending digit of N are equal to 1. What is the smallest
special integer in decimal representation?

Comment: This is a problem from a contest ([NIMO Contest 16](http://internetolympiad.org/monthly/contests/12/problem_file)) which was [ongoing at the time of OP posting it](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20141119T20&p1=179&p2=0).

Answer (score 3):

This last digit conditing just means $N-1$ is divisible by $8$ and $9$. This means that $N-1$ must be amultiple of $72$, so $N=72k+1$ for some $k>0$.

You also need the first digit to be $1$ in both bases. This means that there must be $i,j$ so that:

$$8^i< N<2\cdot 8^i$$

and:

$$9^j< N<2\cdot 9^j$$

We get:

$$8^{i-1}\leq 9k < 2\cdot 8^{i-1}$$

and:

$$9^{j-1}\leq 8k<2\cdot 9^{j-1}$$

So we need to find a $k$ so that $8k$ starts with $1$ base $9$ and $9k$ starts with $1$ base $8$.

We can't get it with $i\leq 2$. With $i=3$, we get $8\leq k\leq 14$. We also need $j=3$, then $11\leq k$. So $k=11$ is the solution, and $N=72\cdot k + 1= 793 = (1071)_9 = (1431)_8$.

Don't think there is much one can do other than trial and error, however.

Comment: This doesn't cover the leading digit also being 1.

Comment: Whoops, misread it.

Comment: Fixed it, @DanUznanski. Thanks